# How to set Static private ip to NIC in Azure using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-networking

I am creating a NIC in Azure using terraform script. by default it's allocate dynamic private ip to NIC. If i select `private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"` then i have to pass Static ip and it's very hard to manage all ips information.

I have tried using like below - [Terraform - provision static ip addresses on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281917/terraform-provision-static-ip-addresses-on-azure)

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "myterraformnic1" {
  count               = "${var.my_count}"
   name                      = "myNIC1"
    location                  = "eastus"
    resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.myterraformgroup.name}"
    network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.myterraformnsg.id}"

    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "myNicConfiguration1"
        subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.myterraformsubnet.id}"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "static"
        private_ip_address            = "${cidrhost("10.0.1.0/24",  4+count.index)}"

    }

    tags = {
        environment = "Terraform Demo1"
    }
}
```

It will work for 1 NIC but it i have already 20 NIC assigned with Static ips then not able to get ips and set available static ip.

How can i automate set private ip to **Static** in terraform code itself ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy solution to this, unfortunately. If you want a NIC with static internal IP then Azure expects you to tell it what IP you want to use, it will not pick on for you. If you look at the [example for doing this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.compute/vm-automatic-static-ip/azuredeploy.json) with an ARM template, they are cheating and setting the IP to dynamic first, so Azure generates an IP and then changing the mode to static.

So in Terraform, you would need to do something similar, create the NIC with a dynamic IP first, then create the same NIC a second time but make it static this time.

The alternative is to use the [cidrsubnet](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/cidrsubnet.html) notation in Terraform to generate a valid IP address in your subnet. This will work, but the problem here is you have no guarantee that this IP is not already in use by other resources in your subnet unless you have created them all with Terraform and made sure to increment the IPs each time.

Comment: i have done the same. first create dynamic and then using ```data``` and ```output``` pass value to private ip to make it static but in this case i have to run 2 times.

Comment: @sam-cogan, you have a typo in the last sentence of the first para, it should read "... and then changing the mode to static"

Comment: @RodionSychev thanks, fixed

Comment: This answer is obsolete, "dynamic" does not behave like described here

Answer (score 1):

So this seems to be a misconception about what "dynamic" means for a private IP in Azure. Creating a NIC in Azure with a "dynamic" private ip means the IP is assigned upon creation of the interface and only freed upon deletion of the interface.

This means it behaves exactly as "static" interfaces.

The only difference is that a "static" interface has a user assigned (as in input parameter) IP, a "dynamic" interface is automatically assigned a free IP from the subnet. I have send a PR to update the tf docs https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/15264

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/12159

Just to make it 100% clear, this does mean a "dynamic" IP never changes unless you delete the ipconfig resource. It won't change on deallocation of the VM, it won't change when your VM crashes and starts on another host.